# Cypher: Avoid duplicate nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher, spring-data-neo4j

Have the below relationship

```
Bob-[:TWINS]-Alice
```

I need to return all twins. Below is the cypher being used but returns duplicates

```
MATCH a-[:TWINS]-b 
RETURN a.name, b.name
```

[I've set this up in Neo4j console here](http://console.neo4j.org/r/ft1lk3).

How not to return duplicates? I know this can be easily fixed by including the direction of the relationship but here the direction is not relevant. So wondering how to avoid duplicates.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the classic way:

```
MATCH a-[:TWINS]-b
WHERE id(a) < id(b)
RETURN a, b
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this one, fist get the name pair ordered, then use the "DISTINCT" to remove the duplicates.

```
MATCH a-[:TWINS]-b 
RETURN DISTINCT CASE WHEN a.name < b.name  THEN a.name + ',' + b.name  ELSE b.name + ',' + a.name END AS result
```

Answer (score 0):

Found one way of doing this but it only works with latest version. I am looking for other ideas that work with earlier versions or simpler than this.

Idea is to eliminate the duplicates using `DISTINCT` on the relationship and then use `startnode` and `endnode` functions to retrieve the nodes for each identified relation

```
MATCH p=a-[r:TWINS]-b 
WITH DISTINCT r AS rel 
WITH startnode(rel) AS n1, endnode(rel) AS n2 
RETURN n1.name, n2.name
```

Comment: why don't just return distinct a.name, b.name?

Comment: @Lisa Tried that "MATCH p=a-[r:TWINS]-b 
RETURN DISTINCT a.name, b.name" This doesn't work.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. I posted another solution that gets the names ordered before using the "DISTINCT".

Answer (score 0):

Relationships are directional and you are using the query form that ignores the direction. Since it appears you have structured your data so that there is a single relationship between twins, then you can have it return the single relationship between twins by restricting your query to a single direction: note the additional **`>`** character in the query, which then requires the relationship to be in that direction for the match.

```
MATCH a-[:TWINS]->b 
RETURN a.name, b.name
```